# Store (x,y) coordinates in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array that looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
```

I want to store in an ArrayList called **neighbors** the right value of 0. However if I call

```
neigbors.add(location[4][1])
```

I will get the value "1", insted of (4,1). Is there any way I can do it?
Let me mention I use these variables:

```
List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[][] locations = new int[5][5];
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use a built in java class like Point.

```
List<Point> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then when you add a point:

```
neighbors.add( new Point( 4, 1) );
```

You could use.

```
List<int[]> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
```

then

```
neighbors.add( new int[]{ 4, 1} );
```

The reason you should use the java class, or create your own, is because it has meaningful hashCode and equals methods. Also, there is no guarantee that an int[] in your list has 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Point` class that stores its x and y coordinate.

```
import java.util.Objects;
public class Point {
    private final int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a `List` of `Point`s.

```java
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.add(new Point(4, 1));
```

Comment: I'd also consider implementing `hashCode` and `equasl` so you can do (fun) things like `new Point(4, 1).equals(new Point(4, 1))` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good point.